# How can I show query on jade template?

Tags: express, mongoose, pug

I am building simple todo web app with express and mongodb. In this application, I submit todo title and todo description and I want to it pops up below my form.

This is my index.jade

```
extend layout

block content
  .container
    form(action='/' method='post')
      p: input(type='text' name='title' placeholder='todo title')
      p: textarea(name='description' placeholder='todo description')
      p: input(type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='submit' value='Submit!')
```

and my app.js is,

```
app.get('/todo', function(req,res,next){
  res.render('index')
)};
app.post('/todo', function(req,res,next({
  Todo.create(req.body.title+req.body.description, function(err, todo){
    if(err) throw err;
    res.json(req.body);
});
});
```

What should I have to add on my jade that shows submitted todo list?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The form action is wrong, alter `form(action='/' method='post')` to `form(action='/todo' method='post')`

Comment: I fixed it, but still it does not show todo list. I believe I have to add some code in jade, don't I?